# AS3 How i can get anchor point (pivot, registration point) position from Display Object

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

I'm gonna get anchor point relatively DisplayObject

example:
 [image]

```
// HOW GET THIS VALUES IN CODE
    Object height = 90px 
    Object width = 40px 

    anchor point X = 20px 
    anchor point Y = 72px 
//  


    real anchor point X =  anchor point X/Object width = 0.5 
    real anchor point y =  anchor point Y/Object height = 0.8
```

thank you in advance

[image]

```
import flash.events.Event;
import fl.motion.*;

run();

var frameID:uint;
var plistText:String;

function run()
{
    plistText = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>\n<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC \"-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN\" \"http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd\">\n<plist version=\"1.0\">\n<dict>\n";
    processFrame(null);
    this.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,processFrame);

}

function processFrame(e:Event)
{
    if (this.currentFrameLabel != null) {
        if (this.currentFrame != 1)
        plistText += "</array>\n";
        frameID = 0;
        plistText += "<key>"+this.currentFrameLabel+"</key>\n<array>\n";
    }
    plistText+="<dict>\n";
    plistText +="<key>FrameID</key>\n<string>"+frameID+"</string>\n"
    frameID++;
    for (var i:uint = 0; i < this.numChildren; i++)
    {
        var currentObject = this.getChildAt(i);
        plistText += "<key>"+currentObject.name+"</key>\n"
        plistText += "<dict>\n"
        plistText += "<key>positionX</key>\n<string>"+currentObject.x+"</string>\n";
        plistText += "<key>positionY</key>\n<string>"+currentObject.y+"</string>\n";
        plistText += "<key>scaleX</key>\n<string>"+currentObject.scaleX+"</string>\n";
        plistText += "<key>scaleY</key>\n<string>"+currentObject.scaleY+"</string>\n";
        plistText += "<key>rotation</key>\n<string>"+currentObject.rotation+"</string>\n";
        plistText += "<key>alpha</key>\n<string>"+currentObject.alpha+"</string>\n";
        plistText += "<key>visible</key>\n<string>"+currentObject.visible+"</string>\n";
        plistText += "</dict>\n"
    }
    plistText+="</dict>\n";
    if (this.currentFrame == totalFrames)
    {
        plistText += "</array>\n</dict>\n</plist>";
        trace(plistText)
        removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, processFrame);
        this.stop();
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to restructure your question - I have no idea what you're asking.

Comment: I need get anchor point position

Comment: This might be useful for implementing your own registration point: http://www.emanueleferonato.com/2010/08/04/changing-a-movieclip-registration-point-on-the-fly-with-as3/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can derive the object's anchor point via `getBounds()` or `getRect()` call. In order to do that, your DisplayObject should have access to stage, otherwise `getBounds()` and `getRect()` return bogus values (tested). Actually, the anchor point corresponds to (0,0) point of the object in its own coordinate space, thus, running `test.getRect(test)` for your test object will return (-20,-18,40,90) - note thay Y coordinate grows downwards, not upwards. Then, you get your upper left point of that rectangle, invert it, voila, the anchor point of the object relative to its dimensions.

```
function getAnchorPoint(o:DisplayObject):Point {
    var onStage:Boolean;
    var p:DisplayObject=o.parent;
    onStage=(o.stage!=null);
    if (!onStage) stage.addChild(o);
    var res:Point=new Point();
    var rect:Rectangle=o.getRect(o);
    res.x=-1*rect.x;
    res.y=-1*rect.y;
    if (!onStage) {
        stage.removeChild(o);
        if (p) p.addChild(o);
    }
    return res;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

**You can't.** The anchors aren't exported, they exist in the ***.fla** file only.

You can, however, implement your own anchor system (as many libraries do), but accessing the ones in the original fla is not possible.

Comment: You cannot change the anchor position at runtime, but you really can get anchor point of an object. Also, they DO exist in SWF, they are just not visible.